# Transposing a complex data set in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a strange data set and I am hoping you all can help me. I have a data set of the levels of certain environmental contaminants which are measured multiple ways along with the limit of detection are present in a group of research participants. I need these in a wide format, but unfortunately they are currently long and the naming conventions don’t easily translate.

This is what it looks like now:

```
ID   Class      Name    Weight Amount_lipids Amount_plasma LOD 


1   AAA Lead    1.55    44.0         10.0      5.00
1   AAB Mercury 1.55    222.0        100.0     75.00
2   AAA Lead    1.25    25.5         12.0      5.00
```

I have tried various forms of Proc Transpose with no luck and this seems to be more complex than what specifying a prefix can handle.

```
by participant_id;
var Name WEIGHT AMOUNT_LIPIDS AMOUNT_PLASMA LOD;
run;
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ID Weight Lead_lip Lead_plas Lead_LOD Mercury_lip Mercury_plas Mercury_LOD
1  1.55   44.0     10.0       5.0     222.0   100.0        75.0
2  1.25   25.5     12.0       5.0     .           .        .
```

What I get is many randomly labelled variables and I am unable to sort it out. Can anyone provide some advice?

Answer (score 2):

Complex transformations usually involve more than one `TRANSPOSE` or `DATA` steps with arrays.  Sometimes an overly complex transformation is a hint that what is really needed is a reporting procedure such as `tabulate` or `report` instead of data transformation.

Here is the double transpose:

```
data have;
input ID   Class $     Name $   Weight Amount_lipids Amount_plasma LOD;datalines;
1   AAA Lead    1.55    44.0         10.0      5.00
1   AAB Mercury 1.55    222.0        100.0     75.00
2   AAA Lead    1.25    25.5         12.0      5.00
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want_intermediate;
  by id weight name;
run;

proc transpose data=want_intermediate out=want;
  by id weight;
  id name _name_;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Richard! I think I will have to tweak this as I am getting an error that ERROR: The ID value "xxxxxxxxxxxx" occurs twice in the same BY group.